# What's the best way to rotate objects identically in their own direction?

Tags: modifiers, transforms, instances

How to rotate these sticks evenly so that they roughly stay in place. I tried to use the array modifier and make them separate objects, and also somehow rotate them in relation to the 3D cursor, but it didn't help.

[image: Image of the tripod]
<sub>(source: [rozetka.ua](https://i8.rozetka.ua/goods/20068121/xoko_xk_mc_210_images_20068121861.jpg))</sub>

Comment: hello, "rotate these sticks evenly so that they roughly stay in place", could you please elaborate?

Comment: [Status quo](https://ibb.co/sQKCnNG) looks like this and I want to make the result like in the picture above.

Comment: Why rotate around 3D cursor didn't work? Leave the 3D cursor at the center, rotate the stick on the X axis as much as you want, choose Transform Pivot Point > 3D Cursor, link-duplicate the stick, rotate 120° on the Z axis?

Comment: The problem is that when I use Y axis (in my case I it), the object rotates on the global one, but the direction is wrong, and it overlaps with another mesh [example](https://ibb.co/CmYP0rf) Transformation orientation don't help

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: [Here it is](https://pasteall.org/blend/c3c5338b1d3e42da962e5ab3c823d4e3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work fine:

- Select the stick called Cylinder.002. Rotate it as much as you want on the X axis, move it until it's correctly placed:

[image]

- Delete the other sticks, select 002, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to link-duplicate, in the *Transform Pivot Point* menu choose *3D Cursor*, rotate 120° on the Z axis:

[image]

- Do it again.
- If you need to animate the sticks, first parent the initial stick to an empty, then duplicate both the empty and the stick, move and rotate, and you'll animate each stick:

[image]

Comment: But I cannot animate those two other sticks. First can be animated simply by inserting keyframe on some frame and then rotating and inserting another keyframe, but other don't follow the direction I want it to be.

Comment: in that case parent the first one to an empty, and when you duplicate, duplicate both the stick and the empty, then animate the sticks only

Comment: I want to point out that they can be animated even without empties, just by choosing local transform orientation,

Comment: sure but it may bug during the animation, that's why it's better to use empties imho. Note that the animation will always be local, whatever you've chosen as orientation mode when you're keyframing